# How to increase font size in Windows CE

Tags: c#, fonts, windows-ce

I'm trying to develop a simple clock program for a Windows CE 5.0 device in my car, using Visual Studio 2008 professional and C#. I had to use .NET 2.0 since 3.5 doesn't work. The clock program was made as a Form application. It consists of a simple label and a timer, that's it. The clock program works on the device, but I only get a standard font and font-size, no matter what font and size I choose in the label properties in Visual Studio. On my computer the program works fine with several fonts and large font sizes. I can not add anything in the Windows/Font directory on my device since it will be erased after every shut down. It is clear the windows CE version is a totally simplified version with nearly no functions. I guess I have to add the font size in a different way in the program file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can call AddFontResource during your application startup to add additional fonts to the system ones:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee489896(v=winembedded.60).aspx
You can use pinvoke.net (http://www.pinvoke.net/) to find the right declaration to use to import this API in your managed code application.

Comment: I tried namespace test2
{
public partial class Test2 : Form
{
int AddFontResource(LPCTSTR lpszFilename);
string filename = @"My Device\FLASH_STORAGE\Font2.FNT";
public Test2()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(155,25,34);
label1.Font = new Font("Font2.FNT", 32, FontStyle.Italic);
label1.Text = "Hello world!";

Comment: I tried the code below but it is not working. Please let me know what is wrong (I'm a beginner)
{
public partial class Test2 : Form
{
int AddFontResource(LPCTSTR lpszFilename);
string filename = @"My Device\FLASH_STORAGE\Font2.FNT";
public Test2()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(155,25,34);
label1.Font = new Font("Font2.FNT", 32, FontStyle.Italic);
label1.Text = "Hello world!";

Comment: I don't see any actual call to AddFontResource here

Comment: You are right, I had problems with putting my question here. Please look at the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674694/how-to-use-addfontresource-in-c-sharp-for-windows-ce-5-0-application-with-net-2

Comment: Ok, but it's not a good idea to post multiple questions on the same topic. People searching for answers will be confused.